# Django Admin list_display add column [count records of related ForeignKey]

Tags: python, django, count, foreign-keys, django-admin

I am new to Python and Django.

I was trying to count the foreign key items/records of a model and display it as a column in the Admin list_display.

So I have a model "Author", as Foreign key to model "Book".

Here's the models.py:

```
class Author(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-name ']
        verbose_name = _('Author')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Authors')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('author_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'Author',
        related_name='menu_items', 
        verbose_name=_('author'),
    )

    bookname= models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
    )

    publisher= models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
    )
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-bookname']
        verbose_name = _('Book')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Books')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bookname

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('book_detail', [self.pk])
```

Here's the admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Author, Book

class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book
    extra = 1

@admin.register(Author)
class LibraryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def NumberOfBooks(self, obj):
        #I guess sth is wrong here when trying to count the book_set
        return obj.book_set.count()

    NumberOfBooks.short_description = "Books Count"
    list_display = ['bookname', 'publisher', 'NumberOfBooks']
    inlines = [BookInline]
```

I want to count how many books each Author wrote, and display like this on the second level of the admin page ***Home>Authors>Author***:

```
 Author | Books Count
Someone1  NumberOfBooks
Someone2  NumberOfBooks
Someone3  NumberOfBooks
Someone4  NumberOfBooks
```

However I get the error:

```
'Author' object has no attribute 'book_set'
```

**1. did I do the obj.book_set.count() wrong?**
I thought `obj.book_set` would refer to "book" under the same "author"(obj), sounds like I misunderstood it but I am not sure how to achieve what I intended to.

**2. Instead, if I wanted to add a field to 'Authors' which would auto-count number of "book" related to each Author, should this be a better approach and so how to do it?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There should be a list with all the available fields on the error page and you should find a field called `menu_items` (that's what you put into `related_name`in your `Book` model).

But that might be not the best option. You should be able to override `get_queryset()` method on your `LibraryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)` class like this:

```
...
from django.db.models import Count
...

@admin.register(Loan)
class LibraryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(LibraryAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.annotate(books_count=Count('menu_items'))

    def books_count(self, inst):
        return inst.books_count

    list_display = ['bookname', 'publisher', 'books_count']
    inlines = [BookInline]
```

This way counting will be done by your DB.

Comment: `
ERRORS:
<class 'arthors.admin.LibraryAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[3]' refers to 'books_count', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'LibraryAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'authors.Author'.`

Comment: That's the error I am getting and I am really confused now...

by the way`@admin.register(Loan)` should be `@admin.register(Author)`, I mistyped it but that's not the problem here, for example sake I changed the names a bit to make it easier to understand.

Comment: I finally get this work by adding:
`def show_books_count(self, inst):
  return inst.books_count

 list_display = ['bookname', 'publisher',  'show_books_count']`
but could you explain why this works and what `(self, inst)` does? can it be simplified and add into the `def get_queryset`?

Comment: You got that error becayse `books_count` property is missing in the `Admin` model class and true, I missed a method like yours. `inst` is a concrete object and it has a `books_count` property because we `annotate()`d the queryset.

Comment: Must we always write another `def` to return the `get_queryset` in order to call it in `list_display`? Is this the best practice or there's a more elegant way to write it? and... what `inst` really meant? I couldn't find explanation in the docs... I want to know a little bit more of the logic behind this becuz it feels like i am just lucky to get it work by copy and editing some code from some random examples...

Comment: We (re)define `get_queryset()` only if we want to change a default one. `inst` is an object in a concrete row of a table. You can read more about custom values in a `list_display` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).

Comment: Why not `return qs.annotate(books_count=Count('book'))`? I have a similar setup, and that's what I'm using. Works like a charm. Am I missing something?

Comment: @GregKaleka there is a `related_name='menu_items'` on the `Book` model. That's why it should be `qs.annotate(books_count=Count('menu_items'))` here.